# How to get list of webElements which is visible only in page

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I wanted to get the list of element which currently present on page as some content hide in page that I don't want to access.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java, you can use [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and do something like,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300/*timeOutInSeconds*/);
ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> condition = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("foo")) 
List<WebElement> allVisibleElements = wait.until(condition);
```

Comment: while the above code shows proper use of ExpectedConditions, it's just getting all elements with id='foo' (which might be one or just a few).

Comment: @JohnnyC Not all. _only_ visible elements

Comment: @nilesh Actually it waits for *all* elements that match the provided locator to be visible. If some never become visible, the wait will time out. I just tested this for a different question.

Comment: @JeffC Correct, thats what `All` means in `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`

Comment: @JeffC I reread the question, and I see what you are saying. I did get it wrong. I'll try to fix this answer. Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: No problem. This question is trickier than I first thought. I was actually answering another question when I realized that this stuff didn't quite work as I thought it did... kinda along the lines of your answer. As I worked through the other answer and tried this out, I found what I said above. I'm actually not sure what the best approach is here. I've seen other answers that wait for presence of elements and then checks for the first visible element and returns it but that's not an answer to this question.

Comment: I think you can filter the complete list of elements down to only those that are visible using `.stream().filter()` and then return that collection. That's probably how I would do it but it's not something I've ever used. Let me know when/if you do update this, I'd like to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void logVisible(WebDriver driver, String couldNotFind) {



     logger.error("Could not find element "+couldNotFind+", but here is what was actually on the page");

     driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[self::div or self::input or self::li  or self::ul or self::button]")).stream()
    .filter(s -> s.isDisplayed())
    .forEach(s -> logger.error(String.format("Visible : Id:%s Tag:%s Class:%s Text:%s",
      s.getAttribute("id"), s.getTagName(), s.getAttribute("class"), s.getText()).replaceAll("  ", " ").replaceAll("\n", " ")));



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches that I would recommend.

1. Find a locator that only finds the visible desired elements. This sometimes happens on website when there are different versions of the site, e.g. mobile, desktop, etc.
2. If #1 doesn't work, we can create a method that takes a locator, finds all elements, and then filters the list down to only those that are visible.

   ```
   public List<WebElement> findVisibleElements(By locator) {
       return driver.findElements(locator).stream().filter(e -> e.isDisplayed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
   ```

   You would then use it like

   ```
   List<WebElement> inputs = SeleniumSandbox.findVisibleElements(By.id("someId"));
   // this is for debugging purposes and should be the count of matching visible elements
   System.out.println(inputs.size());
   // this sends "some text" to the first visible element
   inputs.get(0).sendKeys("some text");
   ```

Comment: I know this is an old question but I ran across it again and have since found a good solution in case others still need one.